# Wrong tab position on account profile

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, profile-page

On my profile page on Stack Overflow I see the `accounts` tab misplaced:
[image: link]
You can see it under the `answers` tab, shouldn't it be aligned with the others?

Browser: chromium 16.0.912.63-2

Comment: No repro with FF8.

Comment: Have you activated anykind of zoom functionality (if in doubt hit `Ctrl + 0` once)?

Comment: No repro with Chrome 16.0.912.63 (on windows)

Comment: Even [with ridiculously large numbers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jhnb5.png), I cannot get it to fail in Chrome on a Mac. Does the horizontal line expand more to the left?

Comment: What OS are you on? That font looks awfully large, either that's a custom font, or something else is off.

Comment: I'm on linux, no zoom enabled, but the solution provided below was ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this when changing the default font size to 28px (instead of the default 16px) so to "fix" it:

Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> --> <kbd>Under the Hood</kbd> --> <kbd>Web Contents</kbd> --> <kbd>Customize fonts</kbd>  and make sure it looks like this:

[image: chrome font size]

You can have as big as 26px but I suspect other things might break so best have it at 16px which should be big enough to read - if not, use the browser Zoom which is not breaking the design.